# Anchor tag not working in Single Page Application

Tags: knockout.js, anchor, single-page-application, durandal

My application is a single page application using the Hot Towel template (durandal.js, knockout.js, require.js).  I am trying to use an anchor to change to another view, but it is not working.  I am using a data-bind (attr property) in an anchor tag with knockout and calling the showAbout method.  Here is my html-

```
  <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: showAbout }">About</a></li>
```

My shell.js viewmodel -

```
 define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/SecurityDataService'],
function (system, router, logger, SecurityDataService) {

    var HasAccess = ko.observable();

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        router: router,
        User: ko.observable(),
        showAbout: showAbout
    };
    return vm;

    function showAbout() {

        router.map([
            { url: 'About', moduleId: 'viewmodels/About', name: 'About', visible: false }
        ]);


        return router.activate('About'); // should show about view
    }

    function activate() {

        $.when($.getJSON('/api/security', function(data) {
            strHasAccess = "";
            if (typeof (data) == "string") {
                strHasAccess = $.parseJSON(data);
                HasAccess = strHasAccess[0].HasAccess;
                vm.User = strHasAccess[0].UserName;
                $('#spnUserName').text(vm.User);
            } else {
                HasAccess = false;
            }

            return strHasAccess;
        })).then(function (HasAccess) {

            if (strHasAccess[0].HasAccess == true) {
                router.mapNav('home');
                router.mapNav('CAApproval');
                vm.User = strHasAccess[0].UserName;
                return router.activate('home');

            }
            else {
                router.map([
                    { url: 'AccessDenied', moduleId: 'viewmodels/AccessDenied', name: 'AccessDenied', visible: false }
                ]);


                return router.activate('AccessDenied'); // should show details page of a particular folder
                log('Access Denied!', null, true);
            }
        });
    }

    function log(msg, data, showToast) {
        logger.log(msg, data, "shell.js", showToast);
    }
});
```

When I mouseover on the anchor, I see the entire activate function, and not the #/about that I was expecting.  What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showAbout` is a function so this is the expected outcome, isn't it? You might try `showAbout()` instead, but you'd have to check if the return value of `router.activate` is the hash you're looking for.

If you could setup non security sensitive entries via router.map earlier, than you wouldn't need a function at all and could simply use `data-bind="attr: { href: '#About'}">About</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#dummy" data-bind="click: showAbout">About</a></li>
```

in your VM,
Assuming that you have a route mapped for 'about'

```
function showAbout() {
   router.navigate('about');
}
```